# CSS only sticky menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a CSS only sticky menu. This menu is inside another `div` under the header of the website. But as the user scrolls it should remain visible on the page. Googling and looking for answers here I found a good example of what I want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/g7x102s4/ (the red div)

My problem is that I'm doing this inside a React app where I can't install any other plugin, so It has to be done in pure CSS. I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-dream-pwnpc?file=/index.html) where I'm trying to get it working. The `menu` class can float inside the menu container, but always visible to the user. It's the same effect from the first link above, just without JavaScript.

Is it possible? If so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add properties position:sticky and top:0 to your menu.

```
.menuContainer .menu {
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple and elegant solution. Never heard of sticky position before =]